# Python:how to split column into multiple columns in a dataframe and with dynamic column naming

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

i have a sample dataset

```
id           value
[10,10]     ["apple","orange"]  
[15,67]      ["banana","orange"] 
[12,34,45]   ["apple","banana","orange"]
```

i want to convert this into

```
id1 id2 id3            value1 value2 value3
10  10  nan           apple  orange   nan
15  67  nan           banana orange   nan
10  10  45            apple  banana  orange
```

- i solved this problem earlier using if else conditions
- but data could be dynamic so it may have more then 3 values.
- How to split into multiple column with renaming it as mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can reconstruct your data with `tolist` and `pd.DataFrame`. Then `concat` everything together again:

```
d = [pd.DataFrame(df[col].tolist()).add_prefix(col) for col in df.columns]
df = pd.concat(d, axis=1)

   id0  id1   id2  value0  value1  value2
0   10   10   NaN   apple  orange    None
1   15   67   NaN  banana  orange    None
2   12   34  45.0   apple  banana  orange
```

Comment: can you explain me your code df[col].tolist()).add_prefix(col)

Comment: `tolist` converts your pandas Series (column) to a Python list: `[[10, 10], [15, 67], [12, 34, 45]]`. `add_prefix` Adds a prefix for your column names, because those are now `0, 1, 2 .. n`. Try running each part and you will see it;s pretty straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[[10, 10], [15, 67], [12, 34, 45]],
                   "value":[['a', 'o'], ['b', 'o'], ['a', 'b', 'o']]})
    
output = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df.columns:
    output = pd.concat([output,
                       pd.DataFrame(df[col].tolist(), columns = [col + str(i+1) for i in range(df[col].apply(len).max())])],
                        axis = 1)
```

Key code is `pd.DataFrame(df[col].tolist(), columns = [col + str(i+1) for i in range(df[col].apply(len).max())])]`.

Here,`df[col].apply(len).max()` is maximum number of elements among lists in a column.
`df[col].tolist()` converts `df[col]` into nested list, and remake it as DataFrame.